# Which roles should I add to my service account utilised by CircleCi?

Tags: circleci, google-container-registry

I'm running tests and pushing my docker images from CircleCi to Google Container Registry. At least I'm trying to.
Which roles does my service account require to be able to pull and push images to GCR?
Even as an account with the role "Project Owner", I get this error:

```
 gcloud --quiet container clusters get-credentials $PROJECT_ID
   Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
   ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) 
   ResponseError: code=403, 
   message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) 
   for "projects/$PROJECT_ID/locations/europe-west1/clusters/$CLUSTER".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) doc, you will need the storage.admin role to Push (Read & Write), and storage.objectViewer to Pull (Read Only) from Google Container Registry.

On the topic of not being able to get credentials as owner, you are likely using the service account of the machine instead of your owner account. Check which account you are using with the [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/):

```
gcloud auth list
```

You can change the service account the machine is using through the UI by first stopping the instance, then editing the service account. You can also use your Google credentials using the [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/):

```
gcloud auth login
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Everything worked as expected after adding the Storage Admin and
Storage Object Viewer role. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you get `Required "___ANYTHING____" permission` message:

- go to Console -> IAM -> Roles -> Create new custom role `[ROLE_NAME]`
- add `container.clusters.get` and/or whatever other permissions you need in order to get the whole thing going (I needed some rights for kubectl for example)
- assign that role (Console -> IAM -> Add+) to your service account